# CPU and GPU running only around 10-15% during machine learning, training is very slow

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, cpu

Question edited, with code added.

I am getting into machine learning (not even deep learning yet) and I notice that calculations take extremely long, while my CPU and GPU don't seem to be working very hard.  I am playing with the MNIST dataset (70000 samples with 784 features each).

My hardware is:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600X 6 core
- GPU: Radeon RX 570
- RAM: 16GM

Windows 10, python 3.8 in jupyter notebook

Here's the code, and the time I measured for each block (cells in jupyter). I have no reference whether these are normal times.  Some seem very long to me, (I used a training set of only 10000 instead of 60000, for demonstration purposes), and what I find strange is that my CPU and GPU hardly go above 10-15%.
My question:

1. is are those times normal for those classification tasks my hardware setup?
2. Why are my CPU and GPU not working harder?  I even wonder if my GPU is doing anything at all.
3. 

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)

X,y = mnist.data, mnist.target
y = y.astype(np.uint8)

some_digit = X[0]
# following code block is just to visualize what the MNIST dataset is
'''
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28,28)
plt.imshow(some_digit_image, cmap = 'binary')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
'''
print( y[0])

# To demonstrate timing, I just took 10000 for training (60000 out of 70000 would make more sense
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:10000],X[10000:],y[:10000], y[10000:]

# first make a binary classifier: 5 or not 5
y_train_5 = (y_train ==5)
y_test_5 = (y_test == 5)

# following takes 703 ms
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3, random_state = 40)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)

sgd_clf.predict([some_digit])

# following takes 1.44 s
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cross_val_score(sgd_clf, X_train, y_train_5,cv=3, scoring='accuracy')

# following takes 1.44 s
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
y_train_predict = cross_val_predict(sgd_clf,X_train, y_train_5,cv=3)
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(y_train_5, y_train_predict)

# following takes 16.8 s
from sklearn.svm import SVC
svm_clf = SVC()
svm_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
svm_clf.predict([some_digit])

# following takes 1.7 s
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
kn = KNeighborsClassifier()
kn.fit(X_train,y_train)

#following takes 57 s
y_train_predict = cross_val_predict(kn,X_train, y_train,cv=3)
print(confusion_matrix(y_train, y_train_predict))
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to decrease training time is to increase batch size. Increase it until GPU usage is near max.